# Python and numpy - converting multiple values in an array to binary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that is rather large, about 1mill.  The distinct number of numbers is about 8 numbered 1-8.

Lets say I want given the number 2, I would like to recode all 2's to 1 and the rest to 0's.

```
i.e. 
2==>1
1345678==0

Is there a pythonic way to do this with numpy?


[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]=> [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]])
>>> np.where(a==2, 1, 0)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Using `numpy.where()` on the result of `a == 2` here seems redundant to me, and it is less efficient than simply *not* calling it.  Any rationale for it?

Comment: Only that I tend to like solutions which are robust to perturbations in the values; no real motivation otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

That's the result of `a == 2` for a NumPy array `a`:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.randint(1, 9, size=20)
>>> a
array([4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6, 6, 1, 8, 7, 1, 7, 8, 7])
>>> a == 2
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (a == 2).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

If you want to change `a` in place, the most efficient way to do so is to use `numpy.equal()`:

```
>>> numpy.equal(a, 2, out=a)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```